# Google Map App Crashes on Runtime

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying create a simple project on Google maps. I have referred many tutorials to do so, but unfortunately my app crashes giving me the following errors.

ERRORS:

```
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2439
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): ... 10 more
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Caused by:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's     AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.D(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.T(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.S(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.nO(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
03-04 17:15:45.766: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): ... 19 more
```

Manfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my key"/>
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_mail.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The crash is saying that your `meta-data` in the `Manifest.xml` file does not have the correct value

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The crash also says that the value of `google_play_services_version` should be **6587000** but the current value is **0**.

Make sure you are importing the `Google Play Services` [library](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) correctly. This is the problem for your crash.

Comment: What do you suggest me do abt the value in the meta-data tag? I tried putting the value manually by doing android:value="6587000" but its giving me the same error.

Comment: @sj8494 You can't put the value manually. Because this crash mainly try to say that the library was not imported successfully. If it was imported successfully, the value will be added correctly....What you have to do is try again to add the library using the following official documentation http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

to

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your google maps meta data in the manifest file. Pls make sure you have added the google play services correctly.
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html